# kinect tutorial using Adobe tools, flasg, as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, kinect

I need some help.
Is there a way to use Kinect (on windows) using Adobe tools? Flash? AS3?

Is there any good tutorial for it.

Basically I need a basic feature - a navigation menu with my own UI.

Can anyone give some links to tutorials? Sample code?

I could not find any but I am sure there are many examples on the web.

Regards
Yoav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible! You need to use an ANE.

I would start here:

This is the git repot for the [AIRKinect](http://www.as3nui.com/air-kinect/) extension

Source:

https://github.com/AS3NUI/airkinect-2-core

Examples:

https://github.com/AS3NUI/airkinect-2-examples

Once you have the files check out this video tutorial on how to get started

http://vimeo.com/38104155

Comment: @user1365799 make sure you mark answers as correct if you find them satisfactory. This will make it easier for you to get more help in the future